# Duplicate entry error in my code

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I want to store data in my database table from one user more than one time but when I tried to save another data it gives me this error --> Duplicate entry 'niklakis' for key 'PRIMARY',
I can understand why that's happens because it gets the same username but I want this happens because I want to store information from this user and be able to retrieve it by using the username in order to get all the data in this table of this specific user.

How can I fix that error?
PS: I want the username to be my primary key.

HERE IS THE CODE...

> if(isset($_POST['submit_next'])) {
>
> ```
> $username = $_SESSION['username'];
> $school = $_POST['school'];
> $degree = $_POST['degree'];
> $website = $_POST['website'];
> $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
> $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
> $start_year = $_POST['start_year'];
> $end_year = $_POST['end_year'];
> $degree_description = $_POST['degree_description'];
>
> $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO education (username,school,degree,website,start_date,end_date,start_year,end_year,degree_description)
> ```
>
> VALUES ('$username','$school', '$degree', '$website',
>   '$start_date','$end_date', '$start_year', '$end_year',
>   '$degree_description')";
>
> ```
> if(!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert))
> {
>     die('error inserting new record');
> }
> header('Location: work_history.php'); }
> else if(isset($_POST['submit_new'])) {
>
> $username = $_SESSION['username'];
> $school = $_POST['school'];
> $degree = $_POST['degree'];
> $website = $_POST['website'];
> $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
> $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
> $start_year = $_POST['start_year'];
> $end_year = $_POST['end_year'];
> $degree_description = $_POST['degree_description'];
>
> $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO education (username,school,degree,website,start_date,end_date,start_year,end_year,degree_description)
> ```
>
> VALUES ('$username','$school', '$degree', '$website',
>   '$start_date','$end_date', '$start_year', '$end_year',
>   '$degree_description')";
>
> ```
> if(!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert))
> {
>     die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
> } }
> ```

The submit_next we have it in order to save data and move to the next page and the submit_new we have it in order to save the current data and then save new.

Comment: Why are you setting the INSERT SQL twice? You can get away with having it once. It's because your username is the primarykey (which is poor design). You're running it twice, when you call `if(!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert))` it runs the query.

Comment: set username to non primary key, otherwise it will not allow any repeating entry

Comment: @Jezzabeanz because I have two different buttons, so what's your solution where should i place the insert in order to work properly for the both buttons?

Comment: @user3782114 that might be a good solution, I will try it and if it is work it will be fine.

Comment: Add an another column as userid and use it for primary key and drop primary key from username

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solution

1. set username to non primary key ( as said by user3782114 )
2. use two table, one to store username , password ( those fields which are unique ) and in other table use other data( like school , website degree etc.) with username as reference key, not as primary key.